# Get sum value with Condition in jasper Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper Ireport 3.7.6. I have fields such as :

- ID
- Saldo

I want to make **Variable** in jasper that contains sum of  fields "Saldo" which is having ID = 2 I've tried many times but it isn't work till now. Can someone help me how?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I've never tried this.. but it possibly helps you.

1st)Create a new variable sum_saldo, and set attributes like below.

```
Varible Class: java.math.BigDecimal
Calculation: Sum
Reset type: Report
Increment type: None
Variable Expression: (($F{ID} == 2)? $F{Saldo}: 0) // I'm not sure here.
```

2nd)Put a TextField at report footer band and set attributes like below.

```
Text Field Expression: $V{sum_saldo}
Expression Class: java.math.BigDecimal
```